# Subquery is returning more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

The below query is giving an error as shown below:

> Sub query is returning more than 1 value. This is not permitted when
>   the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_s_AlphaBotAssociatedUserList] @AlphaBotMasterId INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT u.UserName
    ,u.Id AS UserId
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.AlphaBotMasterSetting AS abms
        WHERE abms.AlphaBotMasterId = @AlphaBotMasterId
            AND ISNULL(abms.IsActive, 0) = 1
        ) AS TotalAlphaBotMasterMarkets
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.UserSessionDetail AS usd
        WHERE ISNULL(usd.IsSessionClosed, 0) = 0
            AND usd.UserSessionId IN (
                SELECT Id
                FROM dbo.UserSessions AS us
                WHERE us.AlphaBotMasterId = @AlphaBotMasterId
                    AND ISNULL(us.IsActive, 0) = 1
                )
        ) AS ConfiguredMarkets
    ,(
        SELECT ISNULL(us.IsActive, 0)
        FROM dbo.UserSessions AS us
        WHERE us.AlphaBotMasterId = @AlphaBotMasterId
        ) IsSessionRunning
FROM dbo.AlphaBotClient AS abc
INNER JOIN dbo.AlphaBotClientPayment AS abcp ON abcp.AlphaBotClientId = abc.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.AbpUsers AS u ON abc.CreatorUserId = u.Id
WHERE abc.AlphaBotMasterId = @AlphaBotMasterId
    AND abcp.Type = 'Confirmed'
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IN`, `NOT IN` or `Exist`, `NOT Exist` withe multiple values.

Your problem is here

```
(SELECT ISNULL(us.IsActive,0) FROM dbo.UserSessions AS us WHERE us.AlphaBotMasterId=@AlphaBotMasterId) IsSessionRunning
```

You should get one value like `SELECT Max(ISNULL(us.IsActive,0))`

Comment: can you please share the correct query with me, @phong

Comment: Where is your subquery returning multiple result?

Comment: this is the whole query

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Please take a look at @arsam

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the sub-query

```
(SELECT ISNULL(us.IsActive, 0)
 FROM   dbo.UserSessions AS us
 WHERE  us.AlphaBotMasterId = @AlphaBotMasterId)
```

since you are not returing a single value here.

You can use `MAX(ISNULL(us.IsActive,0))` instead